# Parse Issue - Expected identifier '('

Tags: objective-c

I cant work out what is wrong here and keep getting Parse Issue fatals on these lines....

```
static SEL IPShow; = @selector(showNavBar:);
static SEL IPHide; = @selector(hideNavBar:);
static SEL IPEmail; = @selector(sendAsEmail:);
static SEL IPHome; = @selector(backToHome:);
```

Its telling me I need to put brackets in somewhere?

Answer (score 8):

```
static SEL IPShow; = @selector(showNavBar:);
//               ^ remove this semicolon
```

Like this:

```
static SEL IPShow = @selector(showNavBar:);
```

And remove all those other semicolons that are in a similar location.